# How to move turtle to edges of the canvas?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there any way to make the cursor (the turtle) go to the right , left, down and upper edge of the canvas?

[Someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315510/939986) to use `turtle.setx()` with argument as `0` to move to leftmost position. But when I do so, the turtle is moved to the default position *(to the center)*.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for turtle graphics?  Specifically the introduction: "Imagine a robotic turtle starting at (0, 0) in the x-y plane.", and http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/turtle.html#turtle.screensize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `window_width()` and `window_height()` functions to determine the size of the window:

This moves the turtle to the right-most edge:

```
import turtle as tt

def main():
    tt.reset()
    print(tt.window_width(), tt.window_height())
    tt.setx(tt.window_width()//2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    tt.mainloop()
```